# Rails js.erb executing within if statement that is false

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

animal.js.erb

```
<% if @animal.type == "Cat" %>

    <% if @animal.meow == "Loud" %>
        alert("Loud Cat");
    <% else %>
        alert("Quiet Cat");
    <% end %>

<% else %>

    <% if @animal.bark == "Ferocious" %>
        alert("Ferocious Dog");
    <% else %>
        alert("Nice Dog");
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When `@animal.type == "Dog"` I stil get an error for `@animal.meow` method does not exist.

Why is it reading that if statement and erroring?

It appears that .erb is executing the `if @animal.meow` statement even when the `@animal.type is "Dog"`

Comment: let's see your animal model, and also `<% if @animal.meow == "Loud %>`,  `<% if @animal.bark == "Ferocious %>` both missing closing double quote

Comment: sorry, error in typing the post

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add closing quote in line     `<% if @animal.meow == "Loud %>` and in     `<% if @animal.bark == "Ferocious %>`

Comment: sorry that was a typo in the question being posted, not the problem itself